# Spotify Advertiser Page

Tags: javascript, href, spotify, ads

I'm making a Spotify Advertiser page, but recently Spotify updated to version 1.0.1.1060.gc75ebdfd and now all the links with `"a href"` are opening in the native browser and not in the micro browser inside Spotify. I already tried using the `"target='_self'"` and that did not work, and as a solution I started using javascript with `location.href` on onClick event and that works. I need to open the page to share on Facebook and Twitter, but it wont open with JS only with `"a href"`

Anyone know what might be or how can it be fix?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, this behavior is not supported any longer. The old client (ie, all versions less than 1.0.0) was built from a combination of web and native views, and therefore the web views were less restricted in terms of what type of content they could open since such content would only live in a small frame.

The new client, however, is essentially a single webview with a native wrapper around it. This solves lots of problems (from both a UX and a technical standpoint), but it also means that there is only one browser shared by all components. If the new client supported `"target='_self'"`, the content opened by your banner ad would take over the **entire** application window area -- including the back/forward buttons, search bar, etc. This is why we now force all external URLs to be opened in the system web browser instead.